# wxPython: control navigation within wx.Lisbook wx.Panels

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

world!

I'd like to ask you one question, a simple solution (I guess) for a nerve-wracking problem I'm encountering using a wx.Lisbook component of wxPython.

In fact, I want to switch from a wx.Panel to another fluently, withou requiring a user input. I've already tried the SetFocus(), Show()/ShowWithEffect() + Hide()/HideWithEffect() methods, without great results.

Show()/Hide() gives the better results, but the selected Thumbnail remains the previous displayed panel...

Any idea of the method or good practice to manipulate wx.Listbook?

Thanks very much by advance for your answers!

Patrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be able to switch between panels? You should check out the various "Book" controls in wxPython, such as the Toolbook, Notebook, AUINotebook, etc. I also wrote a tutorial that's just on switching panels using the menu:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

You could use a wx.Timer to do the switching too if you didn't want any user involvement.